# How to create a Babel file watcher?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I installed Babel, globally, and the ES2105 preset, globally, on MacOS:

```
npm install --global babel-cli
npm install --global babel-preset-es2015
```

They installed to `/usr/local/lib`.

I created `.babelrc` in `/Users/Fred`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

I created a default Babel file watcher:

[image]

However, I get an error every time I make an edit. Where did I go wrong?

```
/usr/local/bin/babel --source-maps --out-file test-compiled.js --presets es2015 /Users/Fred/PhpstormProjects/test/test.js  
Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/Fred"
```

Comment: It's strongly recommended to install babel-cli and presets locally in your project: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation

I assume one of the problems with your setup is that Babel is looking for a preset in the node_module directory under /Users/Fred (where .babelrc file is located), but it's under /usr/local/lib.

Comment: That worked - thanks. When I tried to minify the compiled output by adding an uglify-js file watcher - it worked - but I got trapped in an infinite loop, with endless files being created. How do i solve this?

Comment: `.min.js` files are still JavaScript files, and watcher listens to all them by default (because default watcher scope == 'Project files', File type == 'JavaScript').
As a workaround I can suggest excluding minified files from watchers processing - create a new scope (Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Scopes) with minified files excluded (like `file:.js&&!file:*.min.js`), and choose this scope as your file watcher scope